# Unable to infer generic type with optional parameters

Tags: c#, type-inference, optional-parameters

Given the following method signature, why is it when a parameter is explicitly named the compiler is unable to automatically infer the type? Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is able to infer the type and shows no warnings or errors.

```
IEnumerable<T> ExecuteCommand<T>(
    string commandText,
    string connectionName = null,
    Func<IDataRecord, T> converter = null) { ... }

static SomeClass Create(IDataRecord record) { return new SomeClass(); }

void CannotInferType() {
    var a = ExecuteCommand(
        "SELECT blah",
        "connection",
        converter: Test.Create);
}

void CanInferType() {
    var a = ExecuteCommand(
        "SELECT blah",
        "connection",
        Test.Create);
}
```

Calling it as described in `CannotInferType` and when attempting to compile it the compiler emits `error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Test.ExecuteCommand<T>(string, string, System.Func<System.Data.IDataRecord,T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` Whereas calling it as described in `CanInferType` works as expected.

As stated above, Visual Studio itself reports no problems, and intellisense for the variable `a` shows `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` as expected but for some reason it doesn't compile.

Comment: It would have helped if you'd given a short but *complete* example...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a bug in the C# 4 compiler. It's been fixed in the C# 5 compiler.

I suspect it's not the optional parameter which is causing the problem here - it's the named argument. Try removing the default values for your parameters and I suspect you'll still have the same problem. (It's worth differentiating between optional parameters and named arguments - they're two separate features. They're often used together, but certainly don't have to be.)

That's the conclusion I came to when I sent this bug report to Eric and Mads:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Foo<T>(Func<T> func) {}

    static void Main()
    {
        // Works fine
        Foo(() => "hello");

        // Type inference fails
        Foo(func: () => "hello");
    }
}
```

Happily this now *works* in the C# 5 beta compiler.