# C# optional parameter on func losing generic type inference

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ienumerable, func

I have trivial generic `enum` parse method:

```
public static T Parse<T>(string value) => (T)Parse(typeof(T), value, false);
```

and usage is:

```
    public IEnumerable<DocumentTypesEnum> FileTypeEnums => 
        FileTypes.Split(',').Select(Extensions.StringEnumerator.Parse<DocumentTypesEnum>);
```

**Above compiles fine.**

Adding optional parameter to `Parse<T>`:

```
public static T Parse<T>(string value, bool ignoreCase = false) => 
        (T)Parse(typeof(T), value, ignoreCase);
```

**Now compiler is not happy!**

[image]

It works just fine, supplying argument/type explicitly (that's what error message saying anyway :) ):

```
public IEnumerable<DocumentTypesEnum> FileTypeEnums => 
            FileTypes.Split(',').Select(f => Extensions.StringEnumerator.Parse<DocumentTypesEnum>(f));
```

**But I am curious why compiler is complaining just by adding optional parameter to func selector?**

**Note:** Closest discussion I can find is [Unable to infer generic type with optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898479/unable-to-infer-generic-type-with-optional-parameters), But its more of **named arguments** issue than optional arguments as **John Skeet** stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify this to remove type inference and overload resolution from the picture. What you want is a *method group conversion* that takes optional parameters into account - and that just isn't part of the C# language rules.

Here's a simpler concrete example:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Foo(int x = 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Action action = Foo; // Error
        action();
    }
}
```

That fails to compile, because there's no parameterless `Foo` method (with a `void` return type).

The language spec *could* have been written so that the compiler would generate a method that just called `Foo` with the optional parameter, and then create a delegate referring to that new method, but it isn't written that way. I believe that at the moment, when you create a delegate from a method group conversion, the invocation list of that delegate is always the corresponding method itself, never a sort of "proxy" method.

The relevant part of the C# 5 ECMA standard is section 11.8, which contains:

> The candidate methods considered are only those methods that are applicable in their normal form **and do not omit any optional parameters (§12.6.4.2)**. Thus, candidate methods are ignored if they are applicable only in their expanded form, **or if one or more of their optional parameters do not have a corresponding parameter in D**.

Answer (score 4):

This is because even though you have the optional parameter, compiler resolution doesn't care - parameter signature has to match on the invocation of your `Select()`.

Select's input parameter is more or less `Func<TInput, TOutput>` with `TInput` being `string` and `TOutput` being `DocumentTypesEnum`. In this case, there's no room for another parameter.

When you do your explicit call, you actually create a new `delegate` with an acceptable signature, which then calls your "non acceptable" signature with the hidden/optional parameter.

Comment: Another parameter is optional one, can be omitted, isn't it? Are you suggesting me to do Func<T1, T2, Tout>?

Comment: BishnuRawal almost.  I am suggesting the exact opposite.  Since we don't control Select() directly, it's better to do as @JLRishe suggests and conform your call signatures to what Select() expects.  The nifty optionality of C# parameters doesn't extend to the situation where you are passing in a delegate with a specific signature

Comment: Also, I am specifying `Select()` but to be accurate I should be saying something more like  `Select(Func<TInput, TOutput>)`

Answer (score 4):

Malachi's answer explains why this is happening.

If you want a way to address it cleanly, the answer is to just have two `Parse` methods - one with two parameters, and one with one, and have the latter call the former.

```
public static T Parse<T>(string value, bool ignoreCase) 
    => (T)Parse(typeof(T), value, ignoreCase);

public static T Parse<T>(string value) => Parse<T>(value, false);
```

Comment: Well then we need to be explicit on usage right? I wanted default inference rules to help the case.

Comment: Also why make overloads if optional parameters can serve the same?

Comment: @BishnuRawal: Because optional parameters *don't* do exactly the same thing, as you've seen.

Comment: @BishnuRawal _"Well then we need to be explicit on usage right?"_ No, you can call `.Select(Extensions.StringEnumerator.Parse<DocumentTypesEnum>)` if you define the methods like this. _"Also why make overloads if optional parameters can serve the same?"_ Because they _can't_ serve the same. If you use optional parameters, you will have the problem described in your question.

Comment: And this technique achieves in a clean way what was achieved already with your delegate `f =>` which I'd argue is a reasonable approach too.

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions. @DaisyShipton answer is more elaborated pointing on C# spec, I am accepting it.